# Is Migatte no Gokui the same ability of moving without thinking, as Whis explained to Goku and Vegeta when training them?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

[When Whis was training Goku and Vegeta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyDuKaykyKI), he told them they should try to acquire the ability of having each part of your body moving independently without thinking.

Was Whis talking about Migatte no Gokui, ability Goku got in the last episode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the same thing as explained [here](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Mastery_of_Self-Movement).

For Whis it is not a transformation, so there is no change in his appearance. Goku obtained this ['Ultra Instinct'](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Instinct_%22Omen%22) for a short while in the episode.